# Get Index position of element mutation happened on

Tags: javascript, mutation

My question is about DOM mutations.
Years ago, web developers were able to handling changes made to DOM (known as DOM Mutations).

I used this function to check if an element has been removed from the DOM.
Also I was able to get the index position **index()** of the element before it remove from the DOM:

```
function NodeRemovedEventTrigger() {
jQuery( "body" ).bind(
    "DOMNodeRemoved",
    function( objEvent ){
        // Append event to log display.
        var elem = $(objEvent.target);
        if(elem.hasClass('feed-container')) {
            var i = elem.index();
            console.log(i);//get index position of the element
        }
    }
);
```

}

Since **DOMNodeRemoved** is deprecated and not supported in some browsers, How do I achieve a function similar to the above function with **MutationObserver()** method. My emphasis is getting the **index position**

what I tried doesn't seem to work for me:

```
// select the target node
var target =document.getElementById('post-line');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

    if (mutation.removedNodes) {
        //if the element removed has class='post-container' , then get the index position
        var elem    =   mutation.removedNodes;
        console.log(elem.index());//get index position
    }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true,removedNodes:NodeList[0]};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="post-line">

<div class="post-container">
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="post-container">
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `mutation.previousElement` to get index of the element that was previous to removed one. Then just add `1` to get removed element index:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.removedNodes) {
      var elem = mutation.removedNodes;
      var prevElement = $(mutation.previousSibling.previousElementSibling);
      var removedIndex = prevElement.index() + 1;
      console.dir(removedIndex);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: wow.That worked. You saved me time. I badly needed the index number to splice an array which contains data of the removed element. Thank you again

Comment: I think the google guyz who created the mutationOberser() API should add   a mutationRecord of Index property. That will make things simple.